# Git Bash (MinGW 64) v2.12.2 - how do I change the font size?

Tags: git, mingw, git-bash

How can I change the font size for Git Bash?

This is the web site where I downloaded related application, [click here](https://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

1. ***Right click*** in the upper left corner of the Git Bash window and choose *"Options..."*:

   [image]
2. Click "Text" and "Select". Select an appropriate font size:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Save</kbd> to keep the new settings.

Comment: And what file are these settings stored in?

Comment: What's the "Leading: 2" that appears there? Can it be changed?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Leading: 2"*? Where? What should it be changed to?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, can this be done programmatically ? (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69555256/2348597)

Comment: @James `~/.minttyrc`