# How to change git bash window options save directory?

Tags: git-bash

For some reason git bash picked up one of my network drives I have no access to as default options save directory so when I try to save git bash window options such as font size I get:

[image]

I don't see where in gitconfig, .gitconfig, profile or bash.bashrc I could change where git bash window options are saved to.

Comment: If you type `echo $HOME` is Git Bash, what do you get? That might be informative.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277001/git-bash-how-to-change-where-the-mintty-configuration-file-is-stored

Comment: Git-bash has nothing to do with Git itself. It's a port *of* bash *to* Windows, provided along with Git (as a sort of free bonus) because Git needs a POSIX-ish shell, and there's bash-for-Windows, sitting there, available. What this means is that no *Git* configuration setting will change where git-bash stores its own specific stuff such as these `.minttyrc` settings. You need a git-bash setting. (Or to put it another way, [tag:git-bash] is the right tag, [tag:git] is not.)